# Find point in line which has the same distance from given 2 points

Tags: linear-algebra

How to find point in line $4x+3y-12=0$ whose distance from point $(-1,-2)$ and $(1,4)$ is the same. I really have no idea about that.I would like to know what to do in these kind of problems rather than giving a solution.

Comment: Hint:  the locus of points equidistant from $P,Q$ is the perpendicular bisector of the segment $\overline {PQ}$.

Comment: Convert the implicit equation $4x+3y-12$ into a parametric expression $x=t; y=\tfrac{-4t}{3}+4$ ; then espress the distances by formulas $AM=\sqrt{(x_M-x_A)^2+(y_M-y_A)^2}$ and the same for $BM$. Equate them, you obtain a quadratic in $t$ that you solve.

Comment: @lulu 2 You mean that you first compute the perpendicular bissector (B), **then** you have to find the intersection of  (B) with the given line.

Comment: @JeanMarie  It is an easy matter to get the intersection of the perpendicular bisector and the given line.

Comment: Thank you for answering guys! I solved it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we want

$$( x+1 )^2+(y+2  )^2=$$
$$(  x-1 )^2+( y-4  )^2$$

and $$4x+3y=12$$

the first equality gives

$$1+2x+4+4y=1-2x+16-8y $$

or
$$x=3-3y $$
thus after replacing
$$y=0\;\;,\;x=3$$

the common distance is 
$$\sqrt {20} .$$

Comment: This solution looks easier to me.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The points equidistant from the two points $A=(-1,-2)$  and $B=(1,4)$ are points of the [perpendicular bisector](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2079324/writing-the-equation-of-a-perpendicular-bisector) of the segment $AB$.  And there is one common point of this bisector with the given line.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! This is exactly what I wanted